# I am expecting error that no default constructor as it is deprecated but i am not getting any error?could anyone tell?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

As per cppreference doc:
The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor or user-defined copy assignment operator.

But i am not getting any error like **default constructor not present**.Please correct me if i am wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

class Demo
{
    int val = 100;
public:
  ~Demo()
  {
      std::cout << "destructor called\n";
  }

  Demo& operator= (Demo obj)
  {
      std::cout << "copy assignment operator called\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
    Demo obj1;//I am expecting error here : no default constructor present as it is deprecated
    Demo obj2(obj1);
    return 0;
}
```

//output:

```
destructor called
destructor called
```

Comment: With GCC adding `-Wextra` will generate a warning. Although that is only about the copy constructor, not sure why you expected there to be no default constructor

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean *removed*. It means *is scheduled to be removed in the future*.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl : Ok..suppose it is deprecated...then after deprecation will my program give error to me that 'copy constructor is not present' like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote talks about the *implicitly-defined copy constructor*, i.e. the implicit constructor of the form

```
Demo(const Demo&);
```

not the *implicitly-defined default constructor*, i.e. the constructor of the form

```
Demo();
```

The latter is what you are using in `Demo obj1;` and the quote doesn't apply to it.

The line `Demo obj2(obj1);` should however generate a deprecation warning, because it *does* use the implicitly-declared copy constructor, which is deprecated since C++11.

However, the compilers seem to have decided to not warn about this deprecation in general. For example GCC requires `-Wextra` to emit it. Also, the deprecation has been around for a long time, so it might be questionable whether it will ever actually be removed. Nonetheless, a class declaring a copy assignment and/or destructor explicitly is almost always broken if it doesn't also define a copy constructor explicitly.

Comment: ok...I got it...it is talking about implicit copy constructor and not implicit default constructor. Just one doubt if we are going to deprecate implicit copy constructor then my question is - how my copy operation will work in that case if there is no implicit copy constructor?

Comment: @Mangy You are supposed to define your own copy constructor. The whole reason for the deprecation is that the implicit one is likely not semantically correct for a class that has the copy assignment and/or destructor user-defined.